# Group $G$ acts faithfully on a set $X$ of 5 objects?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> A group $G$ acts faithfully on a set $X$ of 5 objects. The action has
>   two orbits: one of size 2, and one of size 3. What are the
>   possibilities for the group $G$?

I believe the right step is to apply the orbit-stabilizer theorem but I'm not sure how to get started. What's a good way to go about solving this problem?

Comment: Try applying orbit-stabilizer, as you say, and seeing how far it gets you.

Comment: A key fact here is that the group is a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the orbits there are induced actions $G\to S_2$ and $G\to S_3$. The former must be onto, and the latter map has image either all of $S_3$ or else the cyclic subgroup $C_3$ (since $G$ acts transitively on the orbit with three elements and those are the only two transitive subgroups of $S_3$).

Furthermore the product homomorphism $G\to S_2\times S_3$ must be one-to-one since $G$ acts faithfully, which means $G$ can be identified with the image of this map.

[Note that the image of a product homomorphism needn't be a product of images. There is still the possibility to that the map $G\to S_2\times S_3$ is to some extent "diagonal." Indeed since $A_3\cong C_3$ is normal within $S_3$, one may combine a projection $S_3\to S_2$ with the identity $S_3\to S_3$ for a nontrivial embedding $S_3\to S_2\times S_3$.]